# Android repeating alarm calls service, sometimes alarm stops repeating

Tags: android, performance, android-service, repeatingalarm

```
this is how i am starting a repeating service.
  Intent intent2 = new Intent(Main_page.this, SyncService.class);
  final AlarmManager alarm2 = (AlarmManager) 
  Main_page.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pintent2 = PendingIntent.getService(Main_page.this, 0,  intent2, 0);
     alarm2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 2 * 60000, pintent2);
```

is there any chance of alarm stops repeating.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel an intent like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, model.id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(pIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer joel, i wanted to know if the alarm cancel automatically by any chance.